# hide selection in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

We are using [`ng-select`](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) in a project. And i need to provide functionality with dropdown, but my goal is to clear selection box after choose item from drop-down list. Anyone face this problem?

```
 <ng-select 
   #addmanager
   (change)="setLeagueAdmin($event)" 
   [items]="notAdminLeagueMembers"
   bindLabel="title"
   placeholder="Select from list"
   [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
   [virtualScroll]="true"
   [clearable]="true"
   (scrollToEnd)="onAddManagerSscrollEnd()">
 </ng-select>
```

Comment: you mean once you select do you want to remove dropdown list?

Comment: @Chellappan no, i choose item from list, call a function, item removed from list and i need to clear selection box, because preview of item stay on the box.

Comment: what type of form do you using?

Comment: it's no a form, i bind a array and on change event call setLeagueAdmin callback, which remove selected value from notAdminLeagueMembers array. The problem is, label of the value stay on the selected box and i can't clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ViewChild to get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property will be updated.

```
 <ng-select 
   #addmanager
   (change)="setLeagueAdmin($event)" 
   [items]="notAdminLeagueMembers"
   bindLabel="title"
   placeholder="Select from list"
   [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
   [virtualScroll]="true"
   [clearable]="true"
   (scrollToEnd)="onAddManagerSscrollEnd()">
 </ng-select>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('addmanager') ref:ElementRef;
onChange($e){
  console.log($e);
 //set the input element clear 
  this.ref.itemsList['_selected']=[];
}
```

Check the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-q46vpr

Comment: Does not work with the new version (2.12.1) anymore. Because it takes the _selectedModel instead of _selected to display